# Exectuable compiled with C# replaces quotation marks with strange characters (���) when run in Windows 10

Tags: c#, encoding, windows-10, quotation-marks

I have a bit of a strange problem. I've been using an application in Windows 7 for many years, which was  written in C# using VS 2005. I recently updated to Windows 10 and now the application has stopped working. I get the following error in command prompt:

```
'���barnacles' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

After looking around, the issue seems to come from this line in the code:

```
string CommandString = "barnacles-c special_barn1 ";
```

Which happens to be the first instance of quotation marks in the code. What I've tried so far:

- Adding an @ symbol at the start of the string,
- Replacing *barnacles-c special_barn1* with something else
- Replacing "barnacles-c special_barn1 " with a character array defined
  higher up using {'','',''} etc
- Changing the encoding of the files in Notepad++ from UTF-8 to ANSI
- Converting the solution to VS2012

The application seems to work on everyone else's computer that has been upgraded to Win10. The only difference is that I have a slightly newer version. I'm wondering if it might have something to do with my language or regional settings somehow. Other than that I'm stumped.

Comment: No way that message comes from the line of code you posted - all the code does is set a string variable. My guess is that you're then writing this string variable to a text file called `runme.bat` or similar and then running it, and DOS is choking on the byte order mark caused by c# writing UTF8 by default. The Notepad++ conversion of the file to ASCII should have resolved that, so I'm slightly confused unless something went wrong with that. Share more code please, or change your code that writes the bat file to use ASCII encoding:)

Comment: In case it wasn't clear from Caius' comment, this issue has nothing to do with quotation marks. You need to show us how that `CommandString` variable is actually used within the code, and the code surrounding that.